# Artificial Data normalisation as data is put into the database

Tags: artificial-intelligence, normalization

I was wondering if there is a software that can normalise the data for you by looking at the data you enter in the database. Then realising the duplicate data in rows and then splitting that data into two separate tables and linking the tables by foreign keys.
This can really help speedup the development time for the main logic of the code and other unaccounted data you might be putting in the database at the beginning of the development of the application.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to construct a normalized database design simply by analysing data because normalization requires knowledge of semantics and not just content. What you can do is use a CASE tool like [NORMA](http://www.ormfoundation.org/), which will transform a semantic model into a database design in Fifth Normal Form.

Other algorithms to transform a set of dependencies into a normalized database design also exist. You can find them in any good database theory textbook and they're not difficult to implement for yourself.